# Init multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

Just a little shortcut issue.

```
let history = 5
var gradeTimeline = [Int](count:history*12, repeatedValue:0)
```

will init a one-dimenstional array. Is there a way to do that for a 2-dimensional array too? Long form would be:

```
var gradesTimeline = [[Int]]()
for i in 0...10 { gradesTimeline.append(gradeTimeline) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var gradesTimeline = (0..<10).map { _ in [Int](count:12*history, repeatedValue:0) }
```

But, because of the value semantics of `Array` you can also do:

```
var gradesTimeline = [[Int]](count:2, repeatedValue:([Int](count:3, repeatedValue:0)))
```

which results in

```
gradesTimeline: [[Int]] = 2 values {
  [0] = 3 values {
    [0] = 0
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 0
  }
  [1] = 3 values {
    [0] = 0
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 0
  }
}
 18> gradesTimeline[0][0]=10
 19> gradesTimeline[1][2]=20
 20> gradesTimeline
$R4: [[Int]] = 2 values {
  [0] = 3 values {
    [0] = 10
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 0
  }
  [1] = 3 values {
    [0] = 0
    [1] = 0
    [2] = 20
  }
}
```

Comment: So I guess the `repeatedValue` version works only for 1-dimensional arrays (since your solution is just a shortcut of the `for` loop)?

Comment: Oh. I figured it out over night and now see that you found the same answer :-)